# Proof of sylow first theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Im studying the proof of sylows first theorem (from abstract algebra by beachy and balair). I have 2 questions about it, I will present the proof below:

(theorem: Let $G$ be a finite group, if $p$ is a prime such that $p^{\alpha}$ is a divisor of $\mid G \mid$ for some $\alpha \geq 0$, then $G$ contains a subgroup of order $p^{\alpha}$.)

The proof is by induction on $\mid G \mid = n$ where one states that the theorem holds for $n=1$ and assume it holds for all groups of order less than $n$, the proof also makes use of the class equation, $$\mid G \mid = \mid Z(G) \mid + \sum [G:C(x)]$$ where the sum ranges over one entry from each nontrivial conjugacy class. It is split up in two cases:

$\textbf{Case (1)}$: For each $x \notin Z(G)$, $p$ is a divisor of $[G:C(x)]$

$\textbf{Case (2)}$: For some $x \notin Z(G)$, $p$ is not a divisor of $[G:C(x)]$

$\textbf{Proof for case (1):}$
In this case the class equation shows that $p$ must be a divisor $\mid Z(G) \mid$ and so $Z(G)$ contains an element $a$ of order $p$ (by Cauchy´s theorem). Then $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ since $a \in Z(G)$, and so by the induction hypothesis, $G\ / \langle a \rangle$ contains a subgroup of order $p^{\alpha - 1}$, since $p^{\alpha - 1}$ is a divisor of $\mid G\ / \langle a \rangle \mid$. The inverse image in $G$ of this subgroup has order $p^{\alpha}$ since each coset of $\langle a \rangle$ has $p$ elements.

My first question is, what if $G$ is abelian then it doesnt exist an element $x \notin Z(G)$, although it seems like the proof for case 1 will be valid whenever $G$ is abelian, is this the authors intension?

My second question is, I dont understand the last part of the proof for case 1, what does the following sentence mean? "The inverse image in $G$ of this subgroup has order $p^{\alpha}$ since each coset of $\langle a \rangle$ has $p$ elements."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abelian case is trivial by the decomposition theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. So yes, I agree that this is not a clear way to state the cases. One can restate the cases as follows:

Case 1: $|Z(G)|$ is a multiple of $p$ (hence the existence of $a$).

Case 2: $|Z(G)|$ is not a multiple of $p$ (hence the existence of some $x\not\in Z(G)$ that $[G:C(x)]$ is not divisible by $p$).

For your second question, there's a surjective map
$$G\stackrel\pi\to G/\langle a\rangle$$
Assume that $N$ is a subgroup of order $p^{\alpha-1}$ of $G/\langle a\rangle$. So, $N$ contains $p^{\alpha-1}$ cosets of $\langle a\rangle$, each coset has $p$ elements (because $|\langle a\rangle |=p$). Therefore 
$$\pi^{-1}(N)=\bigcup_{x\in N} x$$ 
is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{\alpha}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, although I have one remark. I think case 2 in your answer is invalid, for instance $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$ and hence must be a multiple of $p$ (since its order must divide the order of $G$ by lagrange´s theorem). Or am I missing something here?

By the surjective map, do you mean the homomorphsim $\pi : G \to G \ / \langle a \rangle$ defined by $\pi(x)=x\langle a \rangle$?

Comment: All we know is $|Z(G)|$ is a divisor of $|G|$, nothing says that it is a multiple of $p$. For example, it is possible that $|G|=12$ and $|Z(G)|=2$, which is not divisible by $p=3$. For the second question, yes, that was correct.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking $\mid G \mid = p^{\alpha}$, my mistake.

Comment: @QuangHoang Could you explain what you mean by "N contains $p^{\alpha-1}$ cosets of (a)"? How do you see this?

Comment: @StrangeBrew It's is exactly the definition of quotient group: set of cosets which is also a group.